# Automate downloading of zipped files created on using export now functionality

Tags: apex, data-loader, data-export, automation

How can i automate downloading of zipped files created on using export now functionality.I am using export now functionality and a zipped file is being created .I need to download that file to local system.One way is by clicking download button.But i want other way by automating or scheduling downloading of zipped file.How can i achieve it.